# Function returning incorrect response

Tags: php, mysql, function, oop, if-statement

I've got an issue with a function where it's returning data from the first if() statement as opposed to the secondary if() statement in a function, please see below.

```
function training($type,$tid)
{   
if($type = "id") {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trainroster WHERE DATE = CURDATE()");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {
            $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $id=$array['TID'];  
            }
    else { $id = "1"; }
 return $id;
}
else if($type = "topic"){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trainroster WHERE TID='$tid'");
    $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $topic = $array['TOPIC'];
    return $topic;
}
}
```

Which is being called like this:

```
$training = $connection->training("topic",$row['TID']);
```

When the function is called it's returning the $id as opposed to the $topic even though I'm setting the $type variable to "topic".

Any help greatly appreciated, cheers!

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use '==' instead of '=' to compare

'=' is an assigning operator, if you use it to compare, it will always return true. That's why you are getting id always.

```
if($type == "id") {
....
if($type == "topic"){
....
```

Comment: Of course! I should have know that, I'd just created another function which used the == to compare. Tested and working :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your if statements:

```
if($type = "id")

if($type = "topic")
```

You're assigning, not comparing. They should be:

```
if($type == "id")

if($type == "topic")
```

Answer (score 0):

`if($type = "id")` assigns the string "id" to $type and returns "id" which is true.

As mentioned by Harish Singh you have to write `if($type == "id")`.

A way to prevent this error is to write `if("id" == $type)` which results in an error if you forget one "=".